# Can I carry 5 mobile phones to US from India?

Tags: luggage

I am planning to carry 5 mobile phones with me to US from India. All the phones are new but unpacked. I have laptop too. Am planning to carry evrything in my hand luggage. Is that fine? Or will this put me into trouble?

Comment: It is not the actual number, it is the value. Can you edit the question to include that. In US $ would be best.

Comment: Are you going to sell or leave them in the United States? Then you need to declare them in your customs form.

Comment: @JoErNanO … save for the fact that it has next to nothing to do with it, it's about importing phones *from* India *to* the US.

Comment: Thanks for d response guys! It's for personal use only. Should I pay duty even if it's unpacked?

Comment: I would also suggest being prepared to answer _why_ you have so many phones, probably from everyone/anyone who looks at or scans your luggage.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's perfectly fine. Just declare them as you enter (on any form you might have to fill in and when talking to a customs officer) and they will tell you if you need to pay any tax or duty. As long as you are upfront and proactive, you will not get in trouble. Bringing any invoice or receipt you have is also a good idea.

Comment: yeah, I guess he wants to know how much he'll owe.

Assuming these are to be left in the US of course, if they're all his personal phones maybe he won't owe but it's likely they won't believe him, or if they do, they'll thing he's a drug dealer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys!  It's for personal use only. Should I pay duty on it even if it's unpacked?

Comment: It is the value that makes whether you need to pay duty, not whether they are packed.

Comment: If you're taking goods in to the country (above certain limits that vary from country to country) and they will *remain* in the country, then you are importing them and will be required to pay applicable taxes.